# C error when reading two dimentional array

Tags: c, arrays

Void should read two dimentional array but when it starts second i cycle it crashes any ideas

```
void skaitymas(int ***matrica, int *n)
{   int i,j,o,g,k;

    printf("Iveskite eiluciu ir stulpelius skaiciu \n");
    scanf("%d",n);

    (*matrica)= malloc(sizeof(int)*(*n));

    for(i=0; i<*n; i++)
        (*matrica)[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*(*n));

    for (i=0;i<*n;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<*n;j++){
        scanf("%d", &matrica[i][j]);

    }
```

Comment: Correct the statement scanf("%d",&n); you missed &.More Over the *n in the function argument and the "n" that is used to accept the value is conflicting.

Comment: That is an answer @Madan, not a comment.  You should put it as an answer.

Comment: hi, @BLUEPIXY The int *n means the function argument is expecting a pointer value which is correct.

Comment: @Madan and that is exactly what `n` is as-provided in the parameter list. `&n` would be `int**`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY int* in your previous comment, the * is a binary operator and expects one more operand and hence it gives error.

Comment: @Madan "%d" is request a `int *`. `n` is already `int *`.

Comment: @Madan I do not understand what you are saying.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY can you just give me the actual "c" statement of you are trying to say.

Comment: @Madan `n` is a `int *n` in the parameters of the function.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY k i got it what you are trying to say. but inside the function there are actually two "n" values getting used. one through the argument and other which is used to accept the "n" value. so conflict.

Comment: @Madan Where do you have defined other than parameters?

Comment: @Madan there is only one `n` in the entire function, provided as a parameter, and its type is `int*`. there is no need for `&` when loading it from `scanf`. I have no idea what 'two "n" values' you're talking about.

Comment: `n` should point to a `size_t`, but to an `int`. No need for a sign here, and `size_t` is guranteed to be wide enough. Scan in using `%zu` then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two significant issues in this code (lack of error checking not withstanding)

- Your use of the dereference and address-ofoperators (`[]` and `&`) isn't accounting for [**operator precedence**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). You're also missing a base dereference of the very pointer you just set in the outer allocation.
- You are allocated size based on specified type (`int`), rather than using `sizeof` in conjunction with the specified *pointer variable*. In this case your specified type (`int`) and that of what you're trying to load it with (`int*`) are *not* the same.

Regarding the first, this line:

```
scanf("%d", &matrica[i][j]);
```

should generate this warning, telling you something is wrong:

```
main.c:20:25: Format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'int **'
```

or something similar. If you don't see this, turn up your warning levels. Regardless, review the [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) table.

Regarding the second issue, this line:

```
(*matrica)= malloc(sizeof(int)*(*n));
```

will happily allocate the amount of memory you requested, and if you're (un)lucky, the size of the items allocated (`int`) matches the size of the pointer's underlying type (`int*`). A better way to do this is to use the pointer variable within the allocation statement in conjunction with `sizeof`

```
(*matrica)= malloc(sizeof(**matrica)*(*n));
```

Taking both the above items into account, utilizing pointer-arithmetic for loading the row values, and integrating the row-allocation with row-reading, one implementation could look like this:

```
void skaitymas(int ***matrica, int *n)
{
    int i,j;

    *matrica = NULL;

    printf("Iveskite eiluciu ir stulpelius skaiciu \n");
    if (scanf("%d",n) == 1 && n > 0)
    {
        *matrica = malloc(*n * sizeof(**matrica));
        for (i=0; i<*n; ++i)
        {
            (*matrica)[i] = malloc(*n * sizeof(***matrica));
            for (j=0; j<*n; ++j)
                scanf("%d", (*matrica)[i]+j);
        }
    }
}
```

Leaving a boatload of error checking as an exercise to you. Best of luck.

Comment: Why use this "complicated": `(*matrica)[i]+j)`? As an exercise to the reader? ;-) Why not do a straight forward: `&(*matrica)[i][j])`? However 1+ for all the other corrections and nice mods.

Comment: @alk look at both of those expressions and **honestly** decide which is more "complicated". Sooner or later the OP had better learn pointer math. May as well start now. (and in fact this exercise will likely make that in inevitability).

Comment: Fair enough .... so let's call it "finger exercises" one should practise on a regular base. ;-)

Comment: I didn't say "*less complicate*", but "*[more] straight forward*", btw.

Answer (score 1):

Change this statement

```
(*matrica)= malloc(sizeof(int)*(*n));
```

to

```
*matrica = malloc( sizeof( int * ) * (*n));
```

Also change this loop

```
for (i=0;i<*n;i++)
{
    for (j=0;j<*n;j++){
    scanf("%d", &matrica[i][j]);

}
```

to

```
for (i=0;i<*n;i++)
{
    for (j=0;j<*n;j++){
    scanf("%d", &( *matrica )[i][j]);

}
```

Comment: Or even better for the 1st statment do: `*matrica = malloc(sizeof (**matrica) * (*n));`